# handling SIGINT (ctrl-c) in golang to convert it to a panic

Tags: linux, go, goroutine, sigint, defer-keyword

My goal is to have a handler for SIGINT (i.e., Ctrl-C on the CLI) which will allow deferred function calls to run instead of causing a hard exit. The usecase for this is in a test suite with very long-running tests, I want the CLI user to be able to trigger test cleanup early using Ctrl-C if they want. The test cleanup functions should all be on the deferred function stacks of each of the test functions, so demoting SIGINT to a panic should, in my mind, cause those cleanup functions to run.

The code below is my attempt to do that. If you run this with `go run .`, you'll see

```
$ go run .
regular action ran!
post-Sleep action ran!
deferred action ran!
```

But if you interrupt it during the 5 seconds of sleep, you'll see this instead:

```
regular action ran!^Cpanic: interrupt

goroutine 8 [running]:
main.panic_on_interrupt(0xc00007c180)
        /home/curran/dev/test/main.go:12 +0x5e
created by main.main
        /home/curran/dev/test/main.go:20 +0xab
exit status 2
```

I added the interrupt handler and the goroutine because I thought that would de-escalate the SIGINT into a panic and allow the call to `fmt.Printf("deferred action ran!")` to execute. However, that did not end up being the case.

Here's the code in question:

```golang
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "time"
        "os"
        "os/signal"
)

func panic_on_interrupt(c chan os.Signal) {
        sig := <-c
        panic(sig)
}

func main() {
        c := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
        // Passing no signals to Notify means that
        // all signals will be sent to the channel.
        signal.Notify(c, os.Interrupt)
        go panic_on_interrupt(c)

        fmt.Printf("regular action ran!")
        defer fmt.Printf("deferred action ran!")
        time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)
        fmt.Printf("post-Sleep action ran!")
}
```

Comment: defer is executed on a per-go-routine basis. A panic in goroutine A which is not recovered leads to termination of the program without executing defers in other goroutines B, C, ... . defer is executed when the enclosing function is left. A panic in an other goroutines doesn't lead other functions to be terminated/left, the program is just terminated.

Comment: Ah, I see. That's helpful to know! I think what I need to do then is maintain a global stack of deferred cleanup actions, and to manually pop actions off that stack when SIGINT is received.

Comment: You directly tell another goroutine to panic.  The closest thing you can do is have each goroutine periodically check a "panic state" and `if shouldPanic() { panic() }`

Comment: Go 1.16 introduced [signal.NotifyContext](https://golang.org/pkg/os/signal/#NotifyContext), which may be useful if you're using contexts already or if it's easy enough to add them.

Answer (score 0):

```
func main() {
    fmt.Printf("regular action ran!")
    defer fmt.Printf("deferred action ran!")

    go startLongRunningTest()
    defer longRunningTestCleanupCode()

    //time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)
    //fmt.Printf("post-Sleep action ran!")

    c := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    signal.Notify(c, os.Interrupt)
    <-c
}
```

`time.Sleep()` blocks running goroutine for the specified time.
You may `defer()` cleanup code.
Also, you can run time-consuming tests in separate goroutines instead of panicking there.
Avoid use of `panic()` if possible.